# What does "address is not inside your domain." mean?

Tags: gmail

I've been getting this yellow underline frequently, and was wondering what it meant.

[image]

A quick Google search revealed to me that:

> "The yellow underline means that an address is not inside your domain."

What does this mean, and if I send them emails, do they receive them?
Additionally, can they reply to me?

Comment: Same question on Gmail help forum -> https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/EBaibNtRAiw

Answer (score 3):

Your domain is the part of your email address after the `@` sign.

Emails you send "outside your domain" are no different from any other message: the other person will receive the email and can reply to you just like any other email.

The reason for the yellow color is just to make sure you're aware that you're sending a message to someone who may be outside your company or organization.

Comment: Is it possible to disable this "feature" in the admin console (or elsewhere)?